# Help me understand the use of "would " in a particular sentence (in IELTS Book)

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, ielts

> **Examiner:** Describe a place you have visited in the past.
>
> **Candidate:** [...] When I was a student, I **would** go there all the time and hang out with my friends.

I don't understand what "would" means in this case. Please help me; thanks in advance.

Comment: Related question, [The habitual past “would” versus “simple past” tense](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218370/the-habitual-past-would-versus-simple-past-tense). Did you try to look it up in the dictionary? See the No. 3 definition of [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/would).

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Your question seems to be too basic for this community. For future questions, I'd like to advise you to visit our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but please make sure you take the [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before posting any question. Please don't post the same question on English Language Learners.

Comment: thanks Rathony so much <3 . I tried to look it up in Oxford  but I just looked over . I 'm sorry :(

Comment: Not every dictionary has the same definition. You have to look up at least 2 or 3 dictionaries. As I said, it would be better for you to go to ELL which is a question and answer site for speakers of other languages learning English.

Comment: http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/past-habit-used-towouldpast-simple

Answer (score 1):

In this case, "would" means "I went there often, during the time I was a student". It describes an habit, it is equivalent to "I used to go there often".