# My mama would rock me in the cradle

Tags: grammar

In the lyrics of the song *Cotton Fields* by *Creedence Clearwater Revival* there is the following sentence:

> When I was a little bitty baby
>   my mama would rock me in the cradle

I feel like I understand the meaning, but I can't find out why is `would` used in such way.

What is the difference to the following:

> When I was a little bitty baby
>   my mama rocked me in the cradle

Comment: This is an example of the habitual past tense

Comment: @TimFoster Thank you, can you make that an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The habitual past "would" versus "simple past" tense](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218370/the-habitual-past-would-versus-simple-past-tense) (and there may well be others).

Answer (score 1):

The use of would here is an example of the habitual past tense.

The habitual past tense can be expressed using various constructions. These include:

- Auxiliary "used to" + infinitive
- Auxiliary "would" + infinitive
- Simple past tense

The "would" form is often used with dynamic verbs (such as "to rock") and especially when the subject is 3rd person.

Source: https://www.thoughtco.com/habitual-past-grammar-1690829

Comment: I've voted for a dupe-closure, but the Nordquist article needs to be kept. Perhaps the mods will coalesce the various duplicates.