# "Since" being used in conditional sentences

Tags: word-usage

I've come across this line in a movie:

> Ever since she got her test results back, she'd get mad whenever someone asked her about it.

I've known about how "since" can only be used in present/past perfect tense but in this case, it's a conditional sentence.

Is it true that "since" is usable here? If not, how else should the sentence be rewritten?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question; it's based on a misconception. The conditional usage of 'would' is assumed here, when the habitual past usage is actually involved. See [the habitual past usage of 'would' ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218370/the-habitual-past-would-versus-simple-past-tense). // 'She'd get mad whenever someone asked her about her test results, ever since she got them back.'

Comment: _Ever since_ is a fixed phrase that refers only to the time since some past event; it has nothing to do with conditional/causative _since_ meaning 'because', which is probly the source of this particular zombie rule. I'd never heard of it before, but who knows what nonsense lurks in the heart of English teachers? Ex ELU, semper aliquid nova.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence makes sense and needs no alteration.

> Since = from a particular time in the past until a later time, or until now
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/since)

Hence, during the period that started when the results arrived and has continued until now, she has been in the state that she would get mad when asked about them. Her getting mad is conditional on being asked, and *since* merely defines the period during which she was in this state.

Comment: @user121863 yes she  used to get mad when asked. But her getting mad depended on her being asked and was therefore still conditional on it.

Comment: We are straying from the question. I did not assert the verb itself to be conditional. I assert that the state of getting mad is conditional on being asked first. That is a correct viewpoint.

Comment: The question is: can since be used in a conditional sentence such as the one reported above? The fact is that the sentence is not a conditional one.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is not conditional, there is no hidden "if" anywhere. It is true that sometimes *when* can be used instead of *if*, but here you have *whenever* which means *every/each time*. This sentence speaks of a habitual situation in the past which started at a past moment marked by *ever since*. Therefore,

> Ever since she got her test results back,

does not speak of a condition, but tells you ***when*** that past frequency started. The repeated action in the past is marked by ***would*** in the main clause

> she'd *[would]* get mad

As for the rest of the sentence

> whenever someone asked her about it.

shows you when or ***how often*** that action is repeated. What may have confused you is that the main clause has two time modifiers, one showing when the past situation started and another saying how often the action is repeated. Though the structure of the sentence may seem somewhat particular, it is nevertheless correct to mark different aspects of the past time with two time clauses.